# OpenLayers 6 print map with scale to pdf via jsPDF

Tags: openlayers, export, pdf, mapcanvas

I am using:

- angular 8V,
- Open Layers 6.4 V

I would like to save my OpenLayers map as PDF.

I am able to Print map smoothly using this example.
[OpenLayer Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html).

input Form is: selection of pdfType(orientation, landscape), pdfSize(a4,a3...), DPI(75,150..)..

**Requirements  is:**

1. Print Map only selected Polygon Area with scale of Polygon(scale should be top-left)
   [image: Print-Polygon-Area]
2. Print current map view with background but selected Polygon should have map content.
   [image: Print-view-with-poygon-area]

I have tried these codes before:

```
const orgExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent();
// I have image size
const polygonExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(ImagesizeOnMap);
const polygon = fromExtent(extent);
 const feature = new Feature(polygon);
 const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
});
vectorSource.addFeatures([feature]);
 const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
 source: vectorSource,
});
vectorLayer.set('name', 'polygonPrint');
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

// Here difficulty to find selected polygon scale(like 200mi).. tried with **control.element.innerText**
const orginalMapSize= map.getSize();
const viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
const size = ImagesizeOnMap;// polygon image size
const width = Math.round((pdfSize[0] * resolution) / 25.4);
const height = Math.round((pdfSize[1] * resolution) / 25.4);
map.once('rendercomplete', function() {  
mapCanvas.width = width;
mapCanvas.height = height;
const mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
 document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'),
 function(canvas) {
  if (canvas.width > 0) {
    const opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
    mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
    const transform = canvas.style.transform;
    const matrix = transform
    .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1]
              .split(',')
              .map(Number);
    // Apply the transform to the export map context
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
    mapContext,
    matrix
    );
    mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
   }
  }
 );
mapContext.globalAlpha = 1;
const pdf = new jsPDF(orientation, undefined, undefined);
pdf.addImage(
 mapCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'), 'JPEG', 0, 0, pdfSize[0], pdfSize[1]
);
...
... // From Above Example Link added same code
```

I have tried many solution but can't get the desired result.

Comment: no one help..??

Comment: @all who has experts on this tech.. please understand beginner's issues and problems.. give suggestion or solution.. thank you

Comment: please at least answer this question like **not able to this type  difficult tech questions or suggestions**..

Comment: For frameworks like React or Angular it's very little possibility to get answer for OpenLayers or Leaflet on GIS SE site. On the other side, possibility of getting answer for plain HTML/JS code is very big.

Answer (score 0):

gis s.e. has had declining activity for a long time for some reason.

There are almost 4800 openlayers related questions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers that might offer more feedback.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).